# Maven release plugin: release:prepare-with-pom vs -DgenerateReleasePoms

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

What's the difference between:

> [mvn release:prepare-with-pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html)

and

> [mvn release:prepare -DgenerateReleasePoms=true](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/generate-release-poms.html)

The documentation doesn't distinguish between them.

Answer (score 3):

Does that help you? :) this is the output when you're running

```
mvn release:prepare -DgenerateReleasePoms=true

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0
    :prepare (default-cli) on project test-dependency: Generating release POMs is no
     longer supported in release:prepare. Please run release:prepare-with-pom instea
    d. -> [Help 1]
```